# Scala check if element is present in a list

Tags: string, list, scala, find

I need to check if a string is present in a list, and call a function which accepts a boolean accordingly.

Is it possible to achieve this with a one liner?

The code below is the best I could get:

```
val strings = List("a", "b", "c")
val myString = "a"

strings.find(x=>x == myString) match {
  case Some(_) => myFunction(true)
  case None => myFunction(false)
}
```

I'm sure it's possible to do this with less coding, but I don't know how!

Answer (score 148, accepted):

Just use `contains`

```
myFunction(strings.contains(myString))
```

Comment: What if I don't deal with a string but I need to check if a value is any of a number of possible matches?

Comment: @tutuca, check this [checking-if-values-in-list-is-part-of-string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16046146/checking-if-values-in-list-is-part-of-string).

Answer (score 35):

And if you didn't want to use strict equality, you could use exists:

```
myFunction(strings.exists { x => customPredicate(x) })
```

Answer (score 23):

Even easier!

```
strings contains myString
```

Comment: How is that different from [the accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14267635/8371915)?

Comment: It's fundamentally the same but differences are: 1. Fewer brackets 2. Fewer periods 3. No reference to myFunction 4. more white space. Overall; My answer = 25 characters vs Accepted answer = 38 characters

Comment: It was a rhetoric question ;) To give you a context I got here from [LQP](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/). I didn't recommend deletion, but if you post late answer try provide some additional value. A bit of syntactic sugar it doesn't feel like it, you know. Just saying...

Comment: No problems. I understand. I think it does add value by showing increased simplicity. Thanks anyway though :)

Answer (score 3):

this should work also with different predicate

```
myFunction(strings.find( _ == mystring ).isDefined)
```

Comment: You could just use exists instead of having to use find combined with isDefined

Answer (score 2):

In your case I would consider using Set and not List, to ensure you have unique values only. unless you need sometimes to include duplicates.

In this case, you don't need to add any wrapper functions around lists.

Answer (score -1):

You can also implement a `contains` method with `foldLeft`, it's pretty awesome. I just love foldLeft algorithms.

For example:

```
object ContainsWithFoldLeft extends App {

  val list = (0 to 10).toList
  println(contains(list, 10)) //true
  println(contains(list, 11)) //false

  def contains[A](list: List[A], item: A): Boolean = {
    list.foldLeft(false)((r, c) => c.equals(item) || r)
  }
}
```