# Checking if values in List is part of String

Tags: string, scala, list

I have a string like this:

```
val a = "some random test message"
```

I have a list like this:

```
val keys = List("hi","random","test")
```

Now, I want to check whether the string `a` contains any values from `keys`. How can we do this using the in built library functions of Scala ?

( I know the way of splitting `a` to List and then do a check with `keys` list and then find the solution. But I'm looking a way of solving it more simply using standard library functions.)

Answer (score 81, accepted):

Something like this?

```
keys.exists(a.contains(_))
```

Or even more idiomatically

```
keys.exists(a.contains)
```

Comment: Or `keys exists a.contains`

Comment: Depending on OP's need, <code>val keys = List("mess")</code> will yield what might be a false positive. <code>keys.exists(a.split(' ').contains)</code> might be more accurate.

Comment: This solution is great but I'm having a hard time understanding it. Could you guys help me out?

Comment: @KirdApe it's just a shortcut for `keys.exists(key => a.contains(key))`

Comment: as an extension of this, what would the code be for returning a list of the list items which were found in the string, rather than just a boolean of whether one exists or not?

Comment: @renegademonkey, I think you're looking for `keys.filter(a.contains(_))`

Comment: Is the complexity of contains o(n^2)? Another question is that "exists" will just return a true or false! How can I actually get the matched string?

Answer (score 11):

The simple case is to test substring containment (as remarked in `rarry`'s answer), e.g.

```
keys.exists(a.contains(_))
```

You didn't say whether you actually want to find whole word matches instead. Since `rarry`'s answer assumed you didn't, here's an alternative that assumes you do.

```
val a = "some random test message"
val words = a.split(" ")
val keys = Set("hi","random","test") // could be a List (see below)
words.exists(keys contains _)
```

Bear in mind that the *list* of keys is only efficient for small lists. With a list, the `contains` method typically scans the entire list linearly until it finds a match or reaches the end.

For larger numbers of items, a set is not only preferable, but also is a more true representation of the information. Sets are typically optimised via hashcodes etc and therefore need less linear searching - or none at all.

Comment: Thanks for the response!
"exists" will just return a true or false! How can I actually get the matched string?