# Checking if values in Map is part of String

Tags: string, scala, dictionary, substring, string-matching

I am looking for the exact same thing as in here except for one difference : [Checking if values in List is part of String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16046146/checking-if-values-in-list-is-part-of-string)

,but in my case keys is a Map and NOT a List. I want to perform the checks on the Map's key.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Checking if values in List is part of String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16046146/checking-if-values-in-list-is-part-of-string) (just use `yourMap.keys` instead of `keys`).

Comment: I don't think you understood the question, or I haven't understood your answer. I have defined a Map named "keys" already

Comment: While this is a questionable name choice for a variable of type `Map[String, _]`, `keys.keys` should still work.

Comment: I get it now! Thanks for your answer!!! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to be complementary with other question you posted

```
val map = Map("hi" -> 1, "random" -> 2, "test" -> 3)

val a = "some random test message"

map.keys.exists(a.contains(_))
```