# spark filter string column by contains one of list of strings

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I need to achieve something similar to: [Checking if values in List is part of String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16046146/checking-if-values-in-list-is-part-of-string) in spark. I.e. there is a dataframe of:

```
abcd_some long strings
goo bar baz
```

and an Array of desired words like `["some", "bar"]`.

An UDF with this code would work just fine, however, I would like to have something more efficient. Is there a way to express the `FILTER my_col CONTAINS ONE OF [items]` using the SQL DSL? Perhaps by dynamically constructing a REGEX?

> NOTE: it is not an exat match rather a regular 'CONTAINS' / LIKE '%thing%'. I.e. not an exact match. Otherwise the `isIn` operator would work.

## edit

probably generating some SQL code dynamically is the most efficient way.

```
def orFilterGeneratorMultiContains(filterPredicates:Seq[String], column:String):Column = {

    col(column).contains(filterPredicates(0)) or col(column).contains(filterPredicates(1)) // TODO iterate
  }
  def filterToDesiredApps(filterPredicates:Seq[String], column:String)(df:DataFrame):DataFrame={
      df.filter(orFilterGeneratorMultiContains(filterPredicates, column))
  }
```

So is need to still figure out how to properly iterate the expression.

## edit 2

However, this turns out to be a bit tricky:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.col

val column = col("foo")
val interstingTHings = Seq("bar", "baz", "thing3")

interstingTHings.foldLeft(column) { (filteredOrColumnExpression, predicateItem) =>
  // TODO how to properly nest the OR operator?
  // filteredOrColumnExpression.contains(predicateItem) // generates: Contains(Contains(Contains('foo, bar), baz), thing3)
  filteredOrColumnExpression or filteredOrColumnExpression.contains(predicateItem) // generates: ((('foo || Contains('foo, bar)) || Contains(('foo || Contains('foo, bar)), baz)) || Contains((('foo || Contains('foo, bar)) || Contains(('foo || Contains('foo, bar)), baz)), thing3)) 
  //     TODO but what y really would need is:
  //      col(column).contains("bar") or col(column).contains("baz") or col(column).contains("thing3")
}.explain(true)
```

as it does not generate the correct `OR` nested filter conditions.

Comment: Are you trying to test all items?.. Could you please sample input and desired output?..

Comment: Indeed. All Items. But the list of items will be rather small.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the right idea, but I think you want to use `||` not `or`. Something like:

```
def orFilterGeneratorMultiContains(filterPredicates:Seq[String], column:String): Column = {
  val coi = col(column)
  filterPredicates.map(coi.contains).reduce(_ || _)
}
```

Comment: Indeed. `interstingTHings.map(column.contains).reduce(_ or _).explain(true)` is what I want. And `||` or `or` are equivalent (as far as I know) for the spark-scala-SQL-DSL.

Answer (score 3):

Wouldn't [rlike](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.4.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/Column.html#rlike(java.lang.String)) work in this case?

```
df.filter(col("foo").rlike(interestingThings.mkString("|"))
```