# Check if String contains any item from List

Tags: scala

I am searching for a one line solution to check if a string contain any item from a List.

**Example:**

String: `"This is A and B and C"`

**Expected Output:**

If List  =["A", "B] then `true`

If List = ["C", "D"] then `true`

If List = ["D", "E"] then `false`

I think something like Stream() in Java can solve this but I am not sure hot to use it in Scala.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `exists`.

```scala
val str = "This is A and B and C"
val xs = List("A","C")
val res = xs.exists(s => str.contains(s))
println(res) // True
```

Comment: Thanks dude. But seems like this is duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16046146/checking-if-values-in-list-is-part-of-string#16046198